# Loop a ListView in Java FX 8

Tags: java, loops, javafx, javafx-8

I'm wondering how I can loop my selections in a `ListView`, i.e. if I have the last item selected and press right, I want the first item to get selected, and pressing left makes it return to the end of the list.

I've tried overriding the `selectNext()` method in a class extending `SingleSelectionModel` but could not get it working. Am I even on the right track? :)

-Cheers

Andreas

Comment: the navigational selection methods aren't used internally, in fact they can't be used because the semantics of the model are incomplete (see f.i. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090009 ) The only thing you could do (and I once did sometime around the early jdk8, when I was very bored ;-) is to re-implement the complete stack of ListView/SelectionModel/ListViewSkin and ListViewBehaviour to a) improve the semantics and b) use them in the behaviour

Comment: Ah, I see. To bad they haven't fixed it yet :/. I think re-implementing the complete stack is a bit over my level; the looping isn't really necessary in my program, as it would only enhance the user friendliness a bit :)
Thanks a lot for the answer and the insight though :D

Answer (score 0):

How about trying (in the method that handles "press right")

```
if (list.isSelected(list.getItemCount() - 1))
     list.selectFirst();
```

(where `list` is your object of a subtype of `SingleSelectionModel` )?

Note that `getItemCount()` is abstract so you have to implement it in your subclass.

The converse case would of course test similarly for the index being zero and use

```
selectLast()
```

Comment: I've tried it and the problem is that as soon as the last item gets selected it moves to the beginning, so in other words, I can't select the last item at all. I would also rather modify the `ListView` itself or the `ObservableList` assigned to it, or some class extending them, than code it in a function. Seems less hardcoded and more dynamic :)